# linefill.new opacity Bug

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i'm attempting to create a box using `line.new` and apply color just to test the `linefill.new` function. There seems to be a bug with transparency - even when setting it to 1%, it remains excessively opaque. Is this a bug or could it be an error in my code? I'll include the snippet for reference.

```
//@version=5

indicator('linefill.new test', overlay=true)

int    START_STAMP     = timestamp("1 Oct 2023 00:00")
int    END_STAMP       = timestamp("25 Nov 2023 00:00")

string GROUP_MAIN      = 'Main Settings'
int    start_main_date = input.time(START_STAMP, title='Start',      group=GROUP_MAIN, inline='0')
int    end_main_date   = input.time(END_STAMP,   title='End ',       group=GROUP_MAIN, inline='1')
float  lowPrice        = input.price(50,         title='Lowest',     group=GROUP_MAIN, inline="2")
float  highPrice       = input.price(100,        title='Highest',    group=GROUP_MAIN, inline="2")
color  UpCol           = input.color(color.new(color.red,50),     title='UpCol',    inline="1")
color  DnCol           = input.color(color.new(color.green,50),   title='DnCol',    inline="1")

float middle_hor = (highPrice - ((highPrice - lowPrice)*0.5))

line _bot   = line.new(start_main_date, lowPrice,   end_main_date, lowPrice,   xloc=xloc.bar_time)
line _top   = line.new(start_main_date, highPrice,  end_main_date, highPrice,  xloc=xloc.bar_time)
line _h3    = line.new(start_main_date, middle_hor, end_main_date, middle_hor, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

linefill.new(_top, _h3, color=UpCol)
linefill.new(_bot, _h3, color=DnCol)
```

take a look at this image:
[image]    //------------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have linfills that created on every bar so opacity is stacked

If you change lines to `var` (they wil be created only once)

```
var line _bot   = line.new(start_main_date, lowPrice,   end_main_date, lowPrice,   xloc=xloc.bar_time)
var line _top   = line.new(start_main_date, highPrice,  end_main_date, highPrice,  xloc=xloc.bar_time)
var line _h3    = line.new(start_main_date, middle_hor, end_main_date, middle_hor, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

then it will work

Comment: Ooh now I understand why it happened. Thank you Starr you were very kind and helpful